# How to export mp3 file in sibelius

Tags: sibelius

In Sibelius , I can't export my score as a mp3 file. Because when I'm in export page, I choose my playback configuration that is connected to my digital piano. But it says "you can't use this playback configuration for exporting audio because it does not contain any virtual instruments please choose another playback configuration above"
What should I do?

Comment: This post indicates that you have to use Virtual Instruments to do this. http://www.sibeliusforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=6016

Answer (score 0):

A 'virtual instrument' means Sibelius 7 Sounds or one of the other software playback systems that can be run within Sibelius.   It has no way of 'hearing' the sounds your external keyboard makes, so cannot directly Export an MP3.

If you particularly want the sounds of your external keyboard, record its audio output.  The recorder COULD be another program running on your computer, with the audio out of the keyboard connected to your soundcard inputs.  Or it could be a seperate external recorder.

Answer (score 0):

1. You might just p**lay the midi file by the sound card and record with a mini-jack cable (headphone out -> microphone in)**
2. or load down a **free program midi to wave converter**
3. or let it **convert online midi to mp3**

Answer (score -2):

Try exporting your work as an audio file. Save it in iTunes. Then start a new Garage Band project. Import the file into Garage Band. Convert it to mp3 with Garage Band.

Comment: But the problem is that he CAN'T export an audio file, for the reason explained.  As to format, Sibelius used to only export WAV/AIFF files, direct export of MP3 was enabled in recent versions.  Conversion of WAV to Mp3 can be done in iTunes (and in other ways too).  No need for GarageBand (assuming he has a Mac).  So quite a few reasons to downvote the answer, I'm afraid!

Comment: Yep, you are right.